# Command doesn't forward from FIWARE JSON Agent toward the Broker MQTT

Tags: mqtt, iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I've deployed the iot stack with docker. These are the used containers:

- fiware/orion:1.13.0
- fiware/iotagent-json:1.8.0
- eclipse-mosquitto:1.4.12
- [other containers not involved in the issue ...]

I've registered the following device on the agent:

```
{
     "device_id": "t3",
     "service": "lmobile",
     "service_path": "/lmobile_Industry",
     "entity_name": "t3",
     "entity_type": "Device",
     "endpoint": "tcp://<mqttborker_publicip>:<port>",
     "transport": "MQTT",
     "attributes": [{
                "object_id": "led",
                "name": "led",
                "type": "text"
     }],
     "lazy": [],
     "commands": [{
                "object_id": "c",
                "name": "c",
                "type": "Command"
     }],
     "static_attributes": [
                      ....
     ],
     "protocol": "JSON"
}
```

and the corresponding entity has been properly created on the OCB and when I publish a new measure on the mqttbroker, under the topic `/<apikey>/t3/attrs` the measure is properly forward toward the OCB.

In order to send the command `c` to the device I send the following updateContext on OCB:

```
curl -s -X POST http://<orionhost>:1026/v1/updateContext
       -H 'accept: application/json'
       -H 'cache-control: no-cache' 
       -H 'content-type: application/json'
       -H 'fiware-service: lmobile'
       -H 'fiware-servicepath: /lmobile_Industry'
       -d '{
             "contextElements": [
                 {
                    "type": "Device",
                     "isPattern": "false",
                     "id": "t3",
                     "attributes": [
                       {
                         "name":"c",
                         "type":"Command",
                         "value":100
                       }
                     ]
                 }
             ],
             "updateAction": "UPDATE"
         }'
```

and I receive the following error response:

```
{
     "errorCode": {
         "code": "404",
         "reasonPhrase": "No context element found",
         "details": "invalid context provider response"
     }
}
```

In the OCB Log I can see the following WARNING Message:
`time=Thursday 18 Oct 08:55:54 2018.431Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=postQueryContext.cpp[169]:queryForward | msg=Other Error (context provider response to QueryContext is empty)`.
Anyway, the updateContext is properly forwarded to the Agent.

In the Agent Log (in DEBUG) I can see the followings:

```
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    | time=2018-10-18T09:02:33.975Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=8d2864ec-d2b4-11e8-b445-02420aff0161 | trans=de5680e7-0727-4577-ac44-ddeb59df1f31 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | srv=lmobile | subsrv=/lmobile_Industry | msg=Request for path [/updateContext] from [<agent_publicip>:<port>] | comp=IoTAgent
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    | time=2018-10-18T09:02:33.976Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=8d2864ec-d2b4-11e8-b445-02420aff0161 | trans=de5680e7-0727-4577-ac44-ddeb59df1f31 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | srv=lmobile | subsrv=/lmobile_Industry | msg=Body:
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    | {
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |     "contextElements": [
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |         {
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |             "type": "Device",
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |             "isPattern": "false",
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |             "id": "t3",
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |             "attributes": [
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |                 {
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |                     "name": "c",
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |                     "type": "Command",
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |                     "value": "100"
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |                 }
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |             ]
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |         }
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |     ],
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |     "updateAction": "UPDATE"
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    | }
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    |  | comp=IoTAgent
iotstack_agent-json.1.xyz@xerus-1    | time=2018-10-18T09:02:33.978Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=8d2864ec-d2b4-11e8-b445-02420aff0161 | trans=de5680e7-0727-4577-ac44-ddeb59df1f31 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | srv=lmobile | subsrv=/lmobile_Industry | msg=response-time: 6 | comp=IoTAgent
```

Here I don't see warnings or errors but no commands are forwarded to the MQTT Broker on any topic (I'm subscribed both to the specific topic for commands `/<apikey>/t3/cmd` and to all topics by using the wildcard `#`).

Answer (score 1):

@fgalan is correct - you do not need the `endpoint` field when provisioning a service group for MQTT

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Thing",
     "resource":    ""
   }
 ]
}'
```

However it is essential that `config.json` file is configured correctly to talk to the MQTT Broker.

Personally I'd use `docker-compose` and assign the values using Docker environment variables, but it is also possible to edit the `config.json` file directly:

```
 environment:
     - "IOTA_MQTT_HOST=mosquitto" # The host name of the MQTT Broker
     - "IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883" # The port the MQTT Broker is listening on to receive topics
```

Here is the mapping between `ENV` variables and `config.json` settings:

- `IOTA_MQTT_HOST`  - mqtt.host
- `IOTA_MQTT_PORT`  - mqtt.port
- `IOTA_MQTT_USERNAME`   - mqtt.username
- `IOTA_MQTT_PASSWORD` -    mqtt.password
- `IOTA_MQTT_QOS` - mqtt.qos

Note that `cbroker` is also an optional attribute - if it is not
provided, the IoT Agent uses the default context broker URL as defined in the
configuration file

The [Tutorial](https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT) for provisioning a device over MQTT uses the Ultralight IoT Agent, but the JSON IoT Agent should work in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure, but maybe is a problem at provisioning stage. The `endpoint` starting with `tcp://` is a bit weird to me...

More in detail, looking to [ths piece of documentation](https://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.io/en/master/device_api/index.html#register-your-iot-device) I read:

> The example shows there are two differences comparing [MQTT provision]
>   with provisioning for HTTP:
>
> - The absence of an "endpoint" field
> - The presence of "transport" field, which value has to be "MQTT".

So I understant that you shouldn't use `endpoint` field at all at provisioning time.

Comment: Hi fgalan. Thank you for replying. I tried to publish the same device without the endpoint field. But nothing changed